# Log function with set limits

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, logarithms

I have a general calculus question and I don't exactly know how to solve it.

I want to build a logarithmic function with a known behaviour at limits. Let's say I have a simple function: $log(x)$ and I want to have $\lim_{x \to 0}$ equal to a real number (let's say -2) and $f(5)$ goes to 0. Similarly to

[image: this plot].

In other words, what would be the best function that describes my attached plot?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: From the plot it seems like $f(0)=-2$ and $f(5)=0$.

Comment: You're right, I corrected the question. I got confused while plotting. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You still got it wrong, $f(0)$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}$ refer to the same point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want $f(0)=-2$ and $f(5)=0$. You want something like:$$f(x)=\ln(g(x))$$ You know that $\ln(1)=0$, so you need a transformation $g(5)=1$. You also want $$f(0)=\ln(g(0))=-2$$or $$g(0)=e^{-2}$$
There are many such functions, but a simple possible choice is a linear one:
$$g(x)=ax+b$$You can get one coefficient from $$g(0)=a\cdot 0+b=b=e^{-2}$$
Then the other coefficient is given by $$g(5)=5a+e^{-2}=1$$ or $$a=\frac{1-e^{-2}}5$$
Therefore $$f(x)=\ln\left(\frac{1-e^{-2}}5 x+e^{-2}\right)$$
Using google to graph this:
[image]

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Clear explanation too!

Comment: You are welcome. Note that if you have more constraints, like $f(1), \ f(2),\ ...$, then you can use a polynomial of order number of constraints -1. So for two points you use a line.